# How to deserialize a nested json object into a primitive type based on one of the nested object's field

Tags: c#, json

Say I have this piece of json:

```
[{
    "id": 123,
    "description": "test",
    "group": {
        "id": 456,
        "description": "org"
    }
}]
```

I want to deserialize the JObject above into a C# object. Traditionally I have worked out something like this (where jObject is a JObject loaded from the json string above):

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("group")]
    public Group Group { get; set; }

}

public class Group
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

}

var foo = jObject.ToObject<Item>();
```

What if in the Item class, I just wanted to have a field called GroupId of type int which simply stores the id field from the nested Group object? It would be simple enough to create a method to extract that value onto a field called 'GroupId' in Item, but because the json I'm dealing with has a lot of similarly nested objects where I'm only interested in the id, I'm wondering if I can use JsonSerializer class to accomplish populating a 'GroupId' field automatically upon deserialization somehow? Or if there is another method within the Newtonsoft.Json package that I might not be aware of.

I haven't worked with processing Json extensively, so apologies if this is 100-level stuff; I couldn't find anything that directly addressed this question specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Newtonsoft.Json, I will explain using the same.

When I need to get JSON that is used ONLY for my logic, I tend to do something like this:

For your Item class, what you want to do two things. One, not have to manually set it every time. Two, not have any serialization fail due to that value not being recognized or whatnot.

The first step is to use an Expression Body. This is basically going make the property that you want to act as a simple method, but work just like a property. The second step is simply adding the [JsonIgnore] attribute:

So your Item class becomes this:

```
public class Item
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Property that will be left out of deserialization, but return the Group.Id every time the value is
        /// evaluated.
        /// </summary>
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int GroupId => (int)Group?.Id;

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("group")]
        public Group Group { get; set; }
    }
```

Notice the "GroupId" property that is now part of the items class. What the question mark after the "Group" property will do is ensure that the Group object is not null before attempting to evaluate the id property.

Using your JSON from above, I have just tested this myself in a unit test:

[image]

Please let me know if you need more information about any of the above.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *transform* the `group` JSON object to a single value, assigning it to a property, you can use a custom JsonConverter.

Here, the custom `ObjectToValueConverter` is assigned to the **`GroupId`** property, decorated with `[JsonProperty("group")]`. When the object corresponding to **`group`** is deserialized, the custom converted is called and it will return the Value of the object's `id` Property, if present, converted to `int`. otherwise `0`.

The `Group` class is not used anymore:

```
var myItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);
```

If you instead prefer to preserve the `Group` class object, do what [Kuroiyatsu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162189/7444103) is suggesting.

---

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("group")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectToValueConverter))]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

class ObjectToValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && ((JObject)token).ContainsKey("id")) {
            return (int)token["id"];
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but I'm interested in preserving the class objects as well.

Comment: Sure. I've posted it because this option was missing. It could be useful in some other scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the statement like : 
**var foo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jObject.ToString());**

The first point is JSON looks like an array of objects, so you should be use collection when the time of parsing like List<Item> here.

You can use jobject but in this case, you need to convert it to string like jObject.ToString() here, Or you can pass JSON string directly to the function.

After it you can get the Group Id value by index like :- 
**var GroupId = foo[0].Group.Id;**